# what is the meaning of these two statements?

Tags: javascript, regex

I came across these two statements which are placed inside `for` loop, I tried to make some sense out of them but in vain. can someone please explain to me how they work?

```
 var s = (n === 7 || n === 8) && l.nodeValue;
 if (s ? !/^\??somestring\b/.test(s) : n !== 3 || /\S/.test(l.nodeValue)) break;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set value of `l.nodeValue`  to `s` if `n===7` or `n===8`
2. If `s` is not false then check `!/^\??somestring\b/.test(s)` and reverse the logic value(`!`), if not - check if `n` is not equal or has diffeerent type than `3`
3. Check `/\S/.test(l.nodeValue)`
4. If either 2. or 3. is true, then `break`

Helpfull here is to know that `if...else` may be written as `condition ? true : false`, and that `===` means the variable is equal not only by its value, but in its type, too

Comment: Actually, it will set `s` to `l.nodeValue` if `n` is `7` or `8`. It's important, otherwise the statement would not make sense: `!/^\??somestring\b/.test(s)`.

Comment: You still missed a few. In JS, the ["falsey" values](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) are `false`, `0`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, or an empty string (`""`). Anytyhing else is "Truthy".

Comment: so if `n` is not equal to 7 or 8 dose `s` become false? and if l.nodeValue = false and `n` is equal to 7 or 8 does `s` also become false?

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = (n === 7 || n === 8) && l.nodeValue;
```

If `n` is equal to 7 or 8 set `s` to `l.nodeValue`.

```
if (s ? !/^\??somestring\b/.test(s) : n !== 3 || /\S/.test(l.nodeValue)) break;
```

If `s` is not false:

- If `s` matches `/^\??somestring\b/` do nothing.
- Else `break`.

If `s` is false:

- If `n` is equal to 3 and `l.nodeValue` doesn't match `/\S/` do nothing.
- Else `break`.

Answer (score 0):

code similar like below, I didn't test

```
var s;

if ( n === 7 || n === 8 ){
        s = l.nodeValue;

} else {
        s = false;
}

var isBreakLoop ;

if ( s ){
    isBreakLoop = !/^\??somestring\b/.test(s);
} else {
    if ( n !== 3 ){
        isBreakLoop = true;
    }else {
        isBreakLoop = /\S/.test(l.nodeValue)
    }
}

if( isBreakLoop ) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: No that's not correct... if `s` is `true`, it will always be assigned the value of `l.nodeValue`. I also think that being overly explicit is not really helpful. `s = n === 7 || n === 8;` is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

`(n === 7 || n === 8)` equates to true if n equals 7 or 8

`l.nodeValue` will return its value, if it's not falsey (if `l.nodeValue` isn't `""`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0` or `false`).

Whatever value is on the right-most side of an `&&` will be returned -- not just `true` or `false`.
However, for that to work, of course, everything has to be in place.

So assuming that `l.nodeValue = "Bob";` and `n = 7;`, `s = (true) && "Bob";`, therefore `s === "Bob";`

That's line #1.

Line #2 has a ternary assignment, which returns the value being checked by the `if` statement (the same way `n === 7 || n === 8` returned a `true` for the first check of line 1.

The first regex `/^\??somestring\b/` means a string which either starts with `"?somestring"` or `"somestring"` and then has a word-boundary (space/newline/punctuation/end-of-string).

If `l.nodeValue` was saved to `s`, then test the content of `s` against "somestring..." or "?somestring...".  If there's a match, return false.

If `s` was false (if line 1 fails), then check if `n` equals 3.
Return true if it does NOT match.
If the ternary test which was chosen fails, then check `l.nodeValue` to see if there are any characters which aren't space/newline/tab, at all. Return true if there is.

If any of the test-branches in line #2 result in `true`, then break the loop.